# how to remove the particular string using preg match in php

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-match

I need to remove the `v.` from the vairable how can i do that ?

```
$variable='v.vm_name,p.companyid';
```

**Expected Output**

```
$variable='vm_name,companyid';
```

how can i achive this using preg_match or preg_replace something.

The value will be dynamic something like this

```
 $variable='b.vm_name,tt.companyid';
```

Comment: use preg_replace instead of preg_match

Comment: Why `preg_match`? `str_replace` can do that easily. `str_replace('v.', '', $variable);`

Comment: how can i achievt this in str_replace ?

Comment: Is it on purpose that you removed `p.` also from the string? Is it always [char][dot] that needs to be removed?

Comment: yes ur right done :) @Andreas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$newstr = preg_replace("/(?:\w\.|\w\w\.)/", "$2", $variable);
```

It will remove one or two leading chars and a dot.

Or simply : `$newstr = preg_replace("/(?:\w+\.)/", "$2", $variable);`

Comment: if i use something like this `$variable='tt.vm_name,www.companyid';` this will not workout

Answer (score 2):

Here`s a solution:

```
$variable = 'b.vm_name,tt.companyid';
$variable = preg_replace('/[a-z]+\./', '', $variable);
```

it will remove every dotted prefix before column names.